# How to only push local changes without destroying the container?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have deployed my app (PHP Buildpack) to production with `cf push app-name`. After that I worked on further features and bugfixes. Now I would to push my local changes to production. But when I do that all the images (e.g. profile image) which are being saved on the production server get lost with every push.

How do I take over only the changes in the code without losing any stored files on the production server?

It should be like a "`git pull`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application container should be stateless. To persist data, you should use the offered services. The Swisscom Application Cloud offers an [S3 compatible Dynamic Storage](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/dynamic.html) (e.g. for pictures or user avatars) or different database services ([MongoDB](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/mongodb.html), [MariaDB](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/mariadb.html) and others). If you need to save user data, you should save it in one of these services instead of the local filesystem of the app's container. If you keep your app stateless, you can migrate and scale it more easily. You can find more information about how your app should be structured to run in a modern cloud environment [here](https://12factor.net/). To get more information about how to use your app with a service, please check [this link](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/services/application-binding.html).

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Avoid Writing to the Local File System](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem)

> Applications running on Cloud Foundry should not write files to the
>   local file system for the following reasons:
>
> **Local file system storage is short-lived**. When an application instance
>   crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are
>   reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since
>   the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will
>   start with a new disk image. Although your application can write local
>   files while it is running, the files will disappear after the
>   application restarts.
>
> **Instances of the same application do not share a
>   local file system**. Each application instance runs in its own isolated
>   container. Thus a file written by one instance is not visible to other
>   instances of the same application. If the files are temporary, this
>   should not be a problem. However, if your application needs the data
>   in the files to persist across application restarts, or the data needs
>   to be shared across all running instances of the application, the
>   local file system should not be used. We recommend using a shared data
>   service like a database or blobstore for this purpose.

In future your problem will be "solved" with [Volume Services (Experimental)](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/volume-services-v2.10.html). You will have a persistent disk for your app.

> Cloud Foundry application developers may want their applications to
>   mount one or more volumes in order to write to a reliable,
>   non-ephemeral file system. By integrating with service brokers and the
>   Cloud Foundry runtime, providers can offer these services to
>   developers through an automated, self-service, and on-demand user
>   experience.

Please subscribe to our newsletter for feature announcements. Please also monitor the CF community for upstream development.